# raise exception without closing the generator

Tags: python, exception, generator

Is it possible to raise an exception from generator (deliver only to `.send()` caller),
but without closing the generator in Python?

Consider this code:

```py
def square_plus():
     n = 0
     i = 0
     while True:
         n = yield i + n**2
         i += 1

sp = square_plus()  # create generator
next(sp)            # prime it
print(sp.send(5))   # send 5 and expect 5*5+1
print(sp.send(3))   # send 3 and expect 3*3+2
print(sp.send("boom"))   # send rubbish and expect TypeError without destroying sp
print(sp.send(7))   # send 3 and expect 7*7+3
```

I know I can implement this particular logic for example as a closure, but that's not the point.
This is just an example to keep it simple. I want it to be a generator.
Thanks for any ideas/hints.

*Update:*

I was considering yielding a value or an exception object and wrap generator with a function that will raise exception if value from generator was an exception or return a value otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is catch the exception and return some sentinel value like `None`, and have the user of the generator cooperate by detecting this sentinel and resending a value.

```
def square_plus():
    n = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        n = yield i + n**2
        while True:
            try:
                n = int(n)
            except ValueError:
                n = yield None
            else:
                i += 1
                break

sp = square_plus()  # create generator
next(sp)            # prime it
n = sp.send(5)
if n is not None:
    print(n)
n = sp.send(3)
if n is not None:
    print(n)
n = sp.send("boom")
if n is not None:  # n will be None, so nothing is printed here
    print(n)
n = sp.send(7)
if n is not None:
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Generators don't support that. You can of course wrap your generator in some sort of object that mimics the generator interface, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone posts an answer that does that, but an *actual generator* cannot raise an exception from `send` or `__next__` without terminating.